# Creating a variable based on the values of two other variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variables

I have a dataframe in pandas that include two variables: DEC and TYPE

```
dec     type
 1        13
 2        2
 2        5
 2        7
 2        9
 3        5
```

From these two variables, I would like to create other, binary, variables based on the values of these two variables.

I haven't been able to find code to write exactly what I want, but in python-English, it would be something like:

```
df['new_variable'] = 1 if DEC == 1 & TYPE == 3 or 2 or 1
```

Please let me know if there is something I can include in my question to clarify what I am looking for.

Update from answers:

A problem I am running into occurs because for each variable I need to run two lines of code (below) and when I run the second line it overruns the coding in the first line. How do I run both lines together (i.e. without the second line overrunning the first line)?

```
harrington_citations['gov_winner'] =  np.where((harrington_citations['dec'] == 1) & harrington_citations['type'].isin([1,2,3,4,22]) , 1, 0)

harrington_citations['gov_winner'] = np.where((harrington_citations['dec'] == 2) & harrington_citations['type'].isin([1,5,9,13,18]), 1, 0)
```

Comment: What does `or (V) 2 or (V) 1` means? Where is `V` defined?

Comment: It's neither Python nor English. Can you explain what the condition is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need `.isin` for the second condition and return 1/0:

```
df['new_variable'] = (df['dec'].eq(1) & df['type'].isin([3,2,1])).view('i1')
```

EDIT per comments, you should create 2 conditions with `|` comdition:

```
c1 = (harrington_citations['dec'] == 1) & harrington_citations['type'].isin([1,2,3,4,22])
c2 = (harrington_citations['dec'] == 2) & harrington_citations['type'].isin([1,5,9,13,18])
harrington_citations['gov_winner'] = (c1|c2).view('i1')
```

Comment: A problem arose because of the values needing to be coded twice...please see my edits to the question.

Comment: @GrahamStreich Edited answer , please check

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `np.nan` with whatever value that suits you:

```
df['new_variable'] = np.where((df['dec'] == 1) & df['type'].isin([1,2,3]), 1, np.nan)
```

Comment: what do the last two parameters, '1' and 'np.nan', specify? the value when the condition is met and the value when the condition is not met, respectively? trying to figure it out via this documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: You got that right. You specify them as scalars like in the answer or as an array

Comment: A problem arose because of the values needing to be coded twice...please see my edits to the question.